# bitmap convert small jpg images not heavy images

Tags: android

hi i finally get the problem this is my code which i post earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910206/sqllite-database-work-in-emulator-but-not-work-in-real-device
when i run my application in emulator is work fine and load images which is small like 30 kb 40 kb 50 kb work fine save and retrieve but when i run  my application in read device images is heavy like 700 kb 800 kb so is not save and retrieve application stop unexpectedly what do i do?? help me plz

Comment: Please add some punctuation to your question cause it's a pain to read really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must be getting **Out of Memory Error**. This is because you are rendering more than 500 KB image. Whenever such type of image are rendered to bitmap, they occupy 2 to 5 MBs size in heap.
So you must create a sample size so that image will be displayed as per your screen resolution.

Android Developer has **Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently** article.

*References*

1) http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap

Comment: yes ur right i compress more then 500 kb images what do i do???

Comment: what you need to do is, create a bitmap of sample size (i.e 200*500 width and height respectively). Because, if any image having size 500 KB, may be it has more resolution then you want. Please visit reference link and you will get all the answer, how to load big sized images efficiently in your application.

Comment: this code help me
 Bitmap picture=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard...");
    int width = picture.getWidth();
    int height = picture.getWidth();
    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    int newWidth = 70;
    int newHeight = (int) (70 / aspectRatio);       
    picture= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, newWidth, newHeight, true);

Comment: But this code will already decode bitmap first (in your code its "picture"), and you are scaling image and creating duplicate copy of that file. So its wasting of memory.